# properties.getProperty("queryLocation") returns null

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I am trying to use properties.getProperty(" ") method for reading sql query. But it returns null always. I have gone through respective question and answer but didn't find what I actually need and where I have made wrong.
My .xml configure file is as follows:

```
<bean id="baseDao" class="com.ems.BaseDao.BaseDao" abstract="true">
     <property name="properties" ref="queryPros"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="queryPros" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="singleton" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <value>classpath*:/com/ems/mssqlFile/HomeDao.mssql.sql</value>
            <value>classpath*:/com/ems/mssqlFile/ListDao.mssql</value>
           //both cases problem
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Dao Class as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseDao { 
        protected Properties properties; 
        public void setProperties(Properties properties) { 
        this.properties = properties; 
          } 
       }
public class HomeDao extends BaseDao implements IHomeDao {
   public List<HomeDto> getListFormTable() throws SQLException {
   String query = properties.getProperty("ListDao.getListFormTable");
   org.hibernate.Query hQuery = hibernateQuery(query);
   List<HomeDto> homeDtoList= hQuery.list();
   return  homeDtoList;
  }
}
```

Comment: And you happily not include the properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum, here is my  properties:
`public abstract class BaseDao {
protected Properties properties;
 public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}`

Comment: I mean the content of the property files. and don't add it as comments, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer myself. It was file location error. So, following is correct file location:

```
<bean id="queryPros" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
<property name="singleton" value="true"/>
<property name="locations">
    <list>
      // if file extension specific
       <value>classpath*:/META-INF/mssqlFile/*.sql</value>

       // if file specific
      <value>classpath*:/META-INF/mssqlFile/HomeDao.mssql.sql</value>
      <value>classpath*:/META-INF/mssqlFile/ListDao.mssql</value>

    </list>
</property>
```

**important ! file must be kept in META-INF folder**

Comment: I also kept the file in resource folder and it works properly. META-INF folder is also in resource folder.